# Why scatter chart does not show axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using ChartJS for a project at work, where I try to generate a chart from one or more series of data and some option (chart type, title, type of values of x and y, and so on). Everything is going smooth except of a `scatter` type when I have multiple dataset on data.

```js
var ctx = $('#myChart');

var chart = new Chart (ctx,{
type: "scatter",
  data: {
   "datasets":[
    {
     label:"Series #1",
     fill:false,
     borderColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.4)",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.1)",
     pointBorderColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.7)",
     pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.5)",
     data:[
      {"x":"alpha","y":36.2},
      {"x":"beta","y":36.9},
      {"x":"gamma","y":37},
      {"x":"delta","y":38.3},
      {"x":"epsilon","y":37.9},
      {"x":"zeta","y":37.2}
     ]
    }, {
     label:"Series #2",
     fill:false,
     borderColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.4)",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.1)",
     pointBorderColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.7)",
     pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.5)",
     data:[
      {"x":"alpha","y":37.4},
      {"x":"beta","y":37.1},
      {"x":"gamma","y":36.5},
      {"x":"delta","y":36.4},
      {"x":"epsilon","y":36.4},
      {"x":"zeta","y":36.5}
     ]
    }, {
     label:"Series #3",
     fill:false,
     borderColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.4)",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.1)",
     pointBorderColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.7)",
     pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.5)",
     data:[
      {"x":"alpha","y":38.1},
      {"x":"beta","y":38.4},
      {"x":"gamma","y":39},
      {"x":"delta","y":39.2},
      {"x":"epsilon","y":38.1},
      {"x":"zeta","y":37.4}
     ]
    }],
    "labels":["alpha","beta","gamma","delta","epsilon","zeta"]},
  options: {
   elements: { line: { tension: 0 } },
   scales: {
    xAxes: [
     {
      scaleLabel:{
       display:true,
       labelString:"Date"
      },
      bounds:"data",
      type:"category"
     },{
      display:false
      },{
      display:false
     }
    ],
    yAxes:[
     {
      scaleLabel: {
       display:true,
       labelString:"Temperature (°C)"
      },
      bounds:"data",
      ticks:{
       min:35.9,
       max:39.5,
       autoSkip:false,
       stepSize:0.6
      }
     }, {
      display:false
     }, {
      display:false
     }
    ]
   },
   },
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can easily notice, in my graph there's no grid, no xAxes definition, no yAxes definition. And I don't know why.

So, this is my question: **why my scatter chart do not show grid and axes?**

I give two more hints:

1 - if you play with the snippet changing the chart type from `scatter` to `line`, everything works fine.

2 - The weird xAxes structure is automatically generated since the three passed datasets uses all the same categories. My code create the first xAxes from the first dataset, and create a simple object `{ display: false }` for the other datasets (chart.options.scales.xAxes requires to be an Array of the same size of the Dataset).

I always consider myself a newbie so any suggestion (about this problem, but also about my approach to it) is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `{ display: false }` you can see the gridlines. Not sure if you need this or not?

If you do really need this, then you can always check `if (type === 'line')` and if so you add the `{ display: false }` to the options.

```js
var ctx = $('#myChart');

var chart = new Chart (ctx,{
type: "scatter",
  data: {
   "datasets":[
    {
     label:"Series #1",
     fill:false,
     borderColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.4)",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.1)",
     pointBorderColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.7)",
     pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(0,137,176,0.5)",
     data:[
      {"x":"alpha","y":36.2},
      {"x":"beta","y":36.9},
      {"x":"gamma","y":37},
      {"x":"delta","y":38.3},
      {"x":"epsilon","y":37.9},
      {"x":"zeta","y":37.2}
     ]
    }, {
     label:"Series #2",
     fill:false,
     borderColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.4)",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.1)",
     pointBorderColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.7)",
     pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(19,237,150,0.5)",
     data:[
      {"x":"alpha","y":37.4},
      {"x":"beta","y":37.1},
      {"x":"gamma","y":36.5},
      {"x":"delta","y":36.4},
      {"x":"epsilon","y":36.4},
      {"x":"zeta","y":36.5}
     ]
    }, {
     label:"Series #3",
     fill:false,
     borderColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.4)",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.1)",
     pointBorderColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.7)",
     pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(248,231,28,0.5)",
     data:[
      {"x":"alpha","y":38.1},
      {"x":"beta","y":38.4},
      {"x":"gamma","y":39},
      {"x":"delta","y":39.2},
      {"x":"epsilon","y":38.1},
      {"x":"zeta","y":37.4}
     ]
    }],
    "labels":["alpha","beta","gamma","delta","epsilon","zeta"]},
  options: {
   elements: { line: { tension: 0 } },
   scales: {
    xAxes: [
     {
      scaleLabel:{
       display:true,
       labelString:"Date"
      },
      bounds:"data",
      type:"category",
     }
    ],
    yAxes:[
     {
      scaleLabel: {
       display:true,
       labelString:"Temperature (°C)"
      },
      bounds:"data",
      ticks:{
       min:35.9,
       max:39.5,
       autoSkip:false,
       stepSize:0.6
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   },
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a good solution for my problem, looks like it was easier than I expected. I don't know why but, at first, I believed that creating a number of axes different than the number of dataset create problems on showing data. Thank you!